# Reparametrisation of a model when an interaction is significant to facilitate the interpretation

Tags: interaction, interpretation, model, parameterization

It is admitted that it is complex to interpret main effects when they are involved in an interaction.

Lets take a regular linear model, with two categorical 2 level variables A and B who are interacting together. The model can be written:

```
lm(Response ~ A + B + A:B)
```

Lets call I the intercept, a2 the estimate associated to level 2 of variable A, b2 the estimate associated to level 2 of variable B, and c22 the interaction estimate.

For me, there is 2 cases:

1. The interaction estimate is small compared to main effects
   estimates. In that case, I see no issue in interpreting main effects
   and then specify the interaction is significant but small and
   explain what it changes.
2. The interaction estimate is big compared to
   main effect, and may even change the direction of effects. In that
   case, it is very difficult to interpret estimates, and it is better
   to look the effect of B for each level of A, or the effect of A for
   each level of B, depending on our underlying understanding of the
   interaction between A and B.

We focus on case 2. Let's say B is a modifier of A effect, and I want to look what is the effect of A in each level of B.
To look what the effect of A is for each level of B, one would sum the estimates:

- Effect of A for level 1 of B is a2
- Effect of A for level 2 of B is a2+c22

My issue is that when doing this, we do not know the confidence interval of the effect of A for level 2 of B (i.e. of a2+c22).

Therefore, I wondered whether a good solution to interpret interactions in that case would be to reparametrise the model as:

```
lm(Response ~ B + A:B)
```

This returns two estimates for the interaction instead of one (c21=a2 and c22=a2+previous_c22), so that we directly have the estimated effect of A for each level of B, and moreover we have their confidence intervals.

Is it a good solution? If it is, why don't people do that?

Thanks!

Comment: NB: I take the example of a very simple model, but the aim is to apply to a much more complex (and non linear) model. Therefore, if you see limitations that do not specifically apply here but might apply in other kinds of models, please share.

Comment: I think I found myself a limitation. Lets say I have a third variable C, which interacts as well with A.
In that case, the A:C interaction might as well "absorb" part of the main A effect, so the estimates would change and the interpretation of terms would not be that easy.
I am still open to external points of view.

Comment: And seems the method to calculate the joint confidence interval for a linear model is addressed there:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96018/joint-confidence-interval

Comment: Aurelie - if your comments constitute an answer or at least a large portion of an answer to your question, you might write it up as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I will asap.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a third variable C, which interacts as well with A. The model can be written:

```
lm(Response ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C)
```

When removing the main "A" variable, the model becomes:

```
lm(Response ~ B + C + A:B + A:C)
```

In that case, the A effect does not entirely goes into the A:B interaction, but the A:C interaction might as well "absorb" part of this main A effect, so the estimates would change and the interpretation of terms would not be that easy.

If the only issue is to calculate joint confidence intervals, it is possible for linear models, see this other SE topic:
[Joint Confidence Interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96018/joint-confidence-interval)